# SignalR Server Self Host

Tags: c#, signalr

I need to create a SignalR server self hosted.  I need to put the client on another persons machine to show a demo that pushes data from a remote client on the network to the server to be rebroadcast to any other connected clients.  I have created a signalR server in both windows forms and an asp.net application and they run.  However the URL is Localhost:12345 and works only on my local box. I need to allow other remote clients to connect either with my system IP or a URL.

Thanks

Comment: publish it on azure

Comment: I just set up a SignalR client on Azure, now I am trying to find out how to use the new Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet library to call into the server to send and receive messages.